# vuejs nested json rendering

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am having to work with a json which looks like so:

```
 book_json={ "id": 2, "book": "Rockford mountain", "related_json": { "choice0": " The Good Friday Book", "choice1": "DRiven by Inspiration", "choice2": "Do good, be good", "choice3": "Autobiography Obama", "choice4": "None", "select0": "choice0", "select1": "None" } }
```

In my template, when I render:

```
{{book_json.book} or {{book_json.id}} # all good
```

However, what I would like to display is:

```
{{book_json.related_json.{{book_json.related_json.select0}} }}
// result: `The Good Friday Book`
```

i.e I would like to pick `choice0` which arises from `{{book_json.related_json.select0}}`

I have spent a few hours trying and googleing around, but could not find a way to do this..

Any tips to solve this issue would be much appreciated..

Comment: Hmmm you are trying to get it as `choose0` while it is `choice0` in your json.

Comment: @Mindastic: no, it is not the case. I have now clarified it by changing the json key to make it clearer (I have called it `select0` now)

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be doing `{{book_json.related_json.{{book_json.related_json.select0}} }}` but doing `{{book_json.related_json[book_json.related_json.select0]}}` instead.

Comment: @Mindastic: Hmm.. `{{book_json.related_json[book_json.related_json.select0]}}` seems interesting to try - I have a small problem however - my backend if Django, so I have custom VueJs delimiters set to `[[` `]]` How do I do the inner square brackets as you have mentioned? `[[book_json.related_json[book_json.related_json.select0]]]` - I tried it and it didnt work :(

Comment: If `book_json` is a javascript variable and you want to use it with Vue, then you should call it inside square brackets, not curly braces. `[[book_json.related_json[book_json.related_json.select0]]]`.

Comment: @Mindastic: It is a VueJS `data` which I am iterating through..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205002/discussion-between-mindastic-and-john-m).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
[[ book_json.related_json[book_json.related_json.select0] ]]
```